# OptionSetType protocol Swift

Tags: ios, swift

What’s the purpose of Swift’s `OptionSetType` protocol, and how does it differ from just leveraging `Set` to get those `SetAlgebraType` methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll answer from the practical perspective when using `OptionSetType`. To me, the purpose of `OptionSetType` is to remove all the bit manipulation in C / ObjC.

Consider an example when you have a function that draws the borders of a rectangle. The user can ask it to draw between 0 and 4 borders.

Here's the code in Swift:

```
struct BorderType: OptionSetType {
    let rawValue: Int
    init (rawValue: Int) { self.rawValue = rawValue }

    static let Top = BorderType(rawValue: 1 << 0)
    static let Right = BorderType(rawValue: 1 << 1)
    static let Bottom = BorderType(rawValue: 1 << 2)
    static let Left = BorderType(rawValue: 1 << 3)
}

func drawBorder(border: BorderType) {
    // Did the user ask for a Left border?
    if border.contains(.Left) { ... }

    // Did the user ask for both Top and Bottom borders?
    if border.contains([.Top, .Bottom]) { ... }

    // Add a Right border even if the user didn't ask for it
    var border1 = border
    border1.insert(.Right)

    // Remove the Bottom border, always
    var border2 = border
    border2.remove(.Bottom)
}

drawBorder([.Top, .Bottom])
```

And in C:

```
typedef enum {
    BorderTypeTop    = 1 << 0,
    BorderTypeRight  = 1 << 1,
    BorderTypeBottom = 1 << 2,
    BorderTypeLeft   = 1 << 3 
} BorderType;

void drawBorder(BorderType border) {
    // Did the user ask for a Left border?
    if (border & BorderTypeLeft) { ... }

    // Did the user ask for both Top and Bottom borders?
    if ((border & BorderTypeTop) && (border & BorderTypeBottom)) { ... }

    // Add a Right border even if the user didn't ask for it
    border |= BorderTypeRight;

    // Remove the Bottom border, always
    border &= ~BorderTypeBottom;
}

int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    drawBorder(BorderTypeTop | BorderTypeBottom);
    return 0;
}
```

C is shorter but, at a glance, who can tell what this line does?

```
border &= ~BorderTypeBottom;
```

While this makes instant sense:

```
var border2 = border
border2.remove(.Bottom)
```

It fits into Swift's objective of being an expressive, easy to learn language, compare to the spartan philosophy of C.

Answer (score 2):

`OptionSetType` lets you make your class conform to `SetAlgebraType` without implementing anything, assuming that your class is `RawRepresentable`, and its raw representation is `BitwiseOperationsType`. It does so by providing default implementations to [nine methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_OptionSetType_Protocol/index.html) of `SetAlgebraType`.

The main difference vs. leveraging `Set` is that you do not have to write anything for a good number of types, e.g. integral types. All it takes is making your raw-representable type conform to `OptionSetType`, and you get all implementations for free.

Answer (score 2):

It differs from a Set in that it is *not* a Set. It is an Objective-C enum whose values are bitmasks. The idea is to give you a way to import such an enum into Swift in such a way that you can manipulate it with Set-like convenience and safety, but in reality you are forming an integer using bitwise-and and bitwise-or. In Objective-C, you would have to construct the integer directly, actually using the bitwise-or operator. But Swift saves you from having to do that.

Thus, you *could* say:

```
let val =
    UIViewAnimationOptions.Autoreverse.rawValue |
    UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat.rawValue
let opts = UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: val)
```

...and in Objective-C, you would have to do that, in effect. But Swift lets you say instead:

```
var opts = UIViewAnimationOptions.Autoreverse
opts.insert(.Repeat)
```